# How do I get my eventlistener to respond to the DOM object "ended"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<audio id="audio1">` object and I would like it to do something when the audio has ended. It seems simple, however my code produces no result. This is my javascript:

```
        myAudio=document.getElementById("audio1");
        myAudio.addEventListener('ended', alert('Ha'), true);
```

Eventually I want it to refresh when the audio has ended and then I want to find a way to pre-load an audio track, then have it refresh when the audio ended so there's no load time.

I saw a couple stackoverflow questions on this topic, but they all included many extra things and after trying their methods (the ones I could understand and separate from everything else they were doing), it did not work. I believe I have found the simplest method to do this, but it is not returning a result.

*Currently the function is `alert('Ha')`, however, I will change it to `location.reload(true)` when it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    alert('ha');
}, true);
```

To add an event listener programmatically you need to pass it a function. This wraps it in a lambda/function expression. The way you have it right now is it's passing the return value of `alert('ha')` to `addEventListener` (i.e., undefined).

This is different from when you're using an html attribute; for example, when you have `onclick="..."` you need to give it the actual code to execute.